# How can I clear and recreate the flyway-play generated database during testing

Tags: java, playframework, flyway

I am using Play 2.4 with the [Flyway-Play](https://github.com/flyway/flyway-play) module.

Is there are way to clean and recreate the database between tests using this plugin? Some of my unit test have database effects which are not trivial to reverse, and it would be nice to be able to start afresh after these tests.

The documentation for the flyway-play module states:

> In Test mode, migration is done automatically.

However, this seems be only once before running all tests. It would be nice to have programmatic control when preparing and cleaning up tests.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how flyway is integrated in the play framework (no experience with that), but it looks like what you are looking for is the flyway `clean`command.

> Drops all objects in the configured schemas.

[Flyway documentation: clean](http://flywaydb.org/documentation/command/clean.html)

Comment: I want to recreate the schema after each individual test. Not manually drop the schema at some point.